# Guice Custom Injection for constructor parameters

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I read about Custom Injection in Guice here: 
https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/CustomInjections

This scheme describes how you can create a MembersInjector for injecting fields of a class. I am able to do this successfully. However, I do not like the idea of field injection and would like to do this to inject parameters of a constructor.

Does anybody have a clue as to how this can be achieved for constructor injection?

Specifically:

```
public class PaymentService {
  private final Logger logger;

  @Inject public PaymentService(@InjectLogger(type="log4j") final Logger logger){
       //the @InjectLogger is the injection point
  }


  ...
}
```

The documentation of MembersInjector says "inject dependencies into fields and methods of type T": http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/MembersInjector.html

This seems to indicate that it should be possible to do this.
Any ideas?

Also, to clarify, I need to use custom injection because I don't have the binding at development time. I have to bind a logger at runtime based on the attribute in my annotation from a configuration. I also cannot iterate through all my config keys.

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about Providers, which allow you to decide at run time how to fulfil a given dependency, or else Scopes, which provide you with a means of defining levels at which dependencies are shared. Have you thought about using either of those patterns? https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProviderBindings , https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes

Comment: I actually have an annotation with a string parameter. So I cannot do the binding at development time. So I am forced to use custom injection using TypeListener. Editing the code snippet to show that.

Comment: @Krishnamurthy You cannot do custom injection for **constructor parameters**, only **fields** and **methods**.

Comment: @TavianBarnes I now understand that. It took me a while to read through a lot of documentation to figure that out. Makes me sad.