# Guice Constructor Parameter Custom Annotation Injection

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Is there a way to implement, in `Guice`, injection for a constructor parameter annotated with a custom annotation?

My question is almost exactly the same as this one: [Guice Custom Injection for constructor parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34217920/1177418)

However, that was about 5 years ago.  I would be interested to see if anything has changed.

I need to resolve parameters based on some qualifier like a `name` but those names must be resolved at runtime (i.e. I can't just compile in the `@Named` annotation).

**A contrived example:**

```java
public class MyService
{
  private final DataStore store;

  @Inject
  public MyService(@DataStoreType("sqlite") final DataStore store)
  {
    this.store = store;
  }
  ...
}
```

And *some kind of resolve something or another* dynamic resolver like this:

```java
public DataStore resolve(final DataStoreType annotation)
{
  if ("sqlite".equals(annotation.value())
  {
    return sqliteStore;
  }
  else if ("postgresql".equals(annotation.value())
  {
    return pgStore;
  }
  ...
}
```

For those familiar with `HK2`/`Jersey` I'm looking for something like `org.glassfish.hk2.api.InjectionResolver` in `Guice`

Answer (score 0):

This case may be solved using a [Factory](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject#factories-by-hand). Just move the logic from `resolve()` method to `Factory.create(DataStoreType)`.